# Closed questions shouldn't be advertised

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

When I reading a topic (a question and its answers) on the main board, a list of other questions shows in the right-hand column: titled, "Related".

When I navigate to one of these questions, drawn by what seems like an interesting title, https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3816 I find it's closed: with no answers; and no ability to add an answer (since it's closed).

So: not a satisfactory question to advertise as "Related".

More of a problem in a site which has many closed questions.

Comment: Is this aspect able to be changed for a specific SE site?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bad point but I'd like to say one or two things.

Closed questions are not closed *forever*. You should regard "closed" as a "paused" state. Closed questions can still be edited, because theoretically you can still improve them, not only the OP, but everyone else. Really useless or dangerous questions are locked or deleted.

The "Related" field is showing related questions, regardless of their state, because it's supposed to show the related ones, I suppose; it's not advertising them, in my opinion... But this brings us to the main point above: you can still improve them.

Certainly, if they're not fixable because they'd need extensive editing, then they probably should be deleted after a while, but that's a different matter.